# How fast does a BootCamp installation wake up from sleep?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows

Currently I can't test this myself so maybe somebody could tell me based on their experiences.

If you have installed BootCamp on your MacBook, how fast is it ready for usage when you open the lid? Is it comparable with OSX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used BootCamp with Windows XP and 7 installed on several models of MacBook and MacBook Pro over the last five or so years; in my totally unscientific experience, XP is considerably slower than Windows 7, which is an improvement but still not as fast as OS X.

You might want to refer to [this SuperUser page](https://superuser.com/questions/119189/unpredictable-mbp-wake-from-sleep-in-windows-7-boot-camp) which links to several different AppleCare discussions.